# How to fix 0.3+0.6=0.89999999999 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

When adding two float values, I will get something like:

```
0.3+0.6 = 0.89999999999
```

I know what's going on. In C# we can use decimal instead, but in Javascript, how to fix it?

Comment: If it is just a presentation problem, use `.toFixed` to format the floating point number as a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### MathUtils

```
MathUtils = {
    roundToPrecision: function(subject, precision) {
        return +((+subject).toFixed(precision));
    }
};

console.log(MathUtils.roundToPrecision(0.3 + 0.6, 1)) // 0.9;
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same way, but JavaScript doesn't have a `decimal`-like number type built in. If you search, you can find various implementations like [`big.js`](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) (just an *example*, not a recommendation).

Answer (score 0):

Use a BigNumber library. For example [math.js](http://mathjs.org) has support for bignumbers (powered by [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js)).

Using the expression parser of math.js, you can type natural expressions using bignumbers:

```
// configure math.js to use bignumbers
math.config({number: 'bignumber'});

// evaluate an expression
math.eval('0.3 + 0.6'); // returns a BigNumber with value 0.9
```